# What's the mathematical relationship between Characters, Syllables, Morphemes, Words?

Tags: terminology

Please see the blue box below. The deceased author didn't clearly expound the mathematical relationship between four lexical items. Is my guess correct?

Words ≤  Morphemes  ≤  Characters  ≤  Syllables

> [image]

Henry Rogers [(1940-2010)](https://www.legacy.com/obituaries/thestar/obituary.aspx?n=henry-edwin-rogers-hank&pid=139343744), *Writing Systems* (2004), p 27.

Comment: Hi, this seems to be a spin-off from an earlier question you asked (the relationship between terminologies). You can edit the original question and/or comment on my answer there. I'm voting to close this question here because duplicates should be avoided in Chinese SE.

Comment: I think your proposed inequality looks okay.